# Замена символов по заданному списку

Tags: excel, vba

Есть ли в `Excel` готовая функция для замены символов по заданному списку ?

В данном случае у меня есть строки - в которых попадаются `RU` буквы - их надо заменить на `EN`. Т.е. в текст `У` заменить на  `Y` и т.д.

Но что бы сразу список заготовить и одним нажатием заменить. Ну и не все надо менять символы, а только заданные.

Comment: Нет такой. Уж больно редкая надобность, если не считать перекодировку - но ты ж не станешь создавать кастомную кодировку под эту задачу?

Comment: https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=1&TID=80131&TITLE_SEO=80131-massovaya-zamena-simvolov-na-osnove-tablitsy-sootvetstviya-formulamakr

Comment: Много вложенных SUBSTITUTE в друг друга решили мой вопрос. Вот для примера: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("A1","А","A"),"У","Y")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разместить код в общем модуле, назначить чему-нибудь запуск макроса `Main_`.

Заполнить масивы нужными символами. Заменяемые пары должны находиться в массивах на одинаковых позициях.

Константа `bSwitch` позволяет менять направление замены.

```
Sub Main_()
    Const bSwitch As Boolean = False ' True - Lat->Kir /  False - Kir->Lat '
    Dim aLat(), aKir()

    ' дополнить/заменить символы в массивах '
    aLat = Array("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "D", "d", "E")
    aKir = Array("А", "а", "В", "в", "С", "с", "Д", "д", "ёклмн")

    If bSwitch = True Then
        Call Replace_Symbols(aLat, aKir)
    Else
        Call Replace_Symbols(aKir, aLat)
    End If

    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub

Sub Replace_Symbols(aWhat, aRepl)
    Dim j As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' если нужно, указать конкретный диапазон '
        For j = 0 To UBound(aWhat)
            .Replace What:=aWhat(j), Replacement:=aRepl(j), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
        Next j
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Если диапазон, где происходят замены, большой и макрос замены будет работать долго, нужно диапазон листа переводить в массив и там обрабатывать.

Comment: На данный момент много SUBSTITUTE решили мой вопрос, но, а ваш метод в закладки. Спасибо.